# How to create a view block of one content type filtered by author?

Tags: views, panels

I have a Book Club website which has a page created from a view where different members can add their recommendations. I want to create a block view which can be inserted into a Panel Page for each author, but I am struggling to get the contextual filters and relationships to work.

Below is the basic setup of the view page.

[image]

This is the contextal filter setting.

[image: contextal filter setting]

This now works if I put a user name into the context preview section.
I thought if I added a user context to the panel page this would then allow me to add the user name into the block, but I don't get this option.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! We love to help you. Unfortunately it may be difficult for us to follow you. You are routined inside your specific setup, but we aren't. Do you see any chance to update your question and add more detailed, well structured information (possibly with screenshots attached) to help us to better understand your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how I can reword this to make it clearer, except to say how do I create a view based on user/author content. This is not related to logged in user or to be searchable.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this to work by using a page view with a path /reading-list/% rather than trying to make it work through panels.